# Question about step in a proof regarding a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have a question regarding the proof of **Lemma 4.1** in this [paper](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edrinfeld/Hypergeometric_motives/Beukers-Heckman.pdf). The proof itself isn´t very long. The Lemma reads as follows:

---

*Let $P, Q \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be two $n$ by $n$ matrices having the same characteristic
equation. Suppose there exists a vector $v$ such that $v, Pv, ..., P^{n-1}v$ are linearly
independent (i.e. $P$ is regular). Consider $W= \{X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\mid XP=QX\}$. Then $W$ is
a $\mathbb{C}$-linear vectorspace of dimension at least $n$.*

---

I have a problem, understanding the last step. The author defines a function
$$\phi: \mathbb{C}^n \to W$$
which associates $X$ to $x$ (notation in the proof) and claims that this is linear and injective. Aside from the fact that $X$ is a matrix and thus not even an element in $\mathbb{C}^n$ to begin with, i dont quite get what exactly this function does and hence nor why it has to be linear and injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the author means is that $$\phi: \mathbb C^n \to W, \ x \mapsto X$$
so a vector $x \in \mathbb C^n$ gets mapped to the (unique) matrix $X \in W$ such that $XP^iv = Q^ix$ for $i=0, \dots, n-1$ (that this matrix is actually an element of $W$ is shown in the other part of the proof).
This function in linear because  if $x \mapsto X, y \mapsto Y$ then
$$Q^i(ax+by) = aQ^ix + bQ^iy = aXP^iv + bYP^iv = (aX+bY)P^iv$$ (which now means that $ax+by \mapsto aX+bY$). It is injective because for any given $x$ there is exactly one linear map $f$ that maps the basis of $\mathbb C^n$
$$\{v, Pv, \dots, P^{n-1}v\}$$
to the values
$$\{x, Qx, \dots, Q^{n-1}x\}$$
(this is simple linear algebra: a linear map is uniquely determined by its values on a basis).

This linear map $f$ now has exactly one matrix representation $X$ (w.r.t. to the standard basis) which shows that $\phi$ is injective. Then by the rank nullity theorem we have
$$n= \dim(\mathbb C^n) = \dim(\text{Im}(\phi)) \le \dim(W)$$